# Which Language Attribute is Correct?

Tags: html, lang

I'm sure this has been asked a million times before, and I've googled it a few times, but I'm struggling here and need your help.

Which is correct for the HTML5 LANG attribute? en-US or en_US?

For example;

```
<html lang="en-US">
```

or

```
<html lang="en_US">
```

Your opinions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spec uses a dash `-` as a delimiter to specify `language-extlang`: http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/ so:

```
<html lang="en-US">
```

This is almost always the case when specifying langauge. The exceptions are frameworks like Django they may use an `_` instead on the backend.

Answer (score 4):

According to  [BCP 47](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) (RFC 5646 and RFC 4647) "en-US" seems to be correct.

It refers to the **IANA** [Language](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) Subtag and [Language Tag Extensions](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-tag-extensions-registry/language-tag-extensions-registry) registries.

I suggest you should refer to the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

From [the spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47#section-2.1):

> A language tag is composed from a sequence of one or more
>   "subtags",    each of which refines or narrows the range of language
>   identified by    the overall tag.  Subtags, in turn, are a sequence of
>   alphanumeric    characters (letters and digits), distinguished and
>   separated from    other subtags in a tag by **a hyphen ("-", [Unicode]
>   U+002D)**

So `en-US` is correct..